# My CSS is not linking up to my HTML

Tags: html, css, linker

It is not linking up and I have no idea why. Is it getting confused with other files? I am not entirely sure what to do as I have been trying for the last hour. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Desktop/task/style.css"/>
<title>It's all about me!</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
</header>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">What I love</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>

h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a Desktop folder at the same level as the html document, your path to the css file is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your path to your css file is likely not correct double check that it is correct. also you have some css outside of a style tag (That should be in the head in the first Place) at the bottom of the page ensure that you delete that before continuing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your css file is not accessible to your web page. make sure it is in the same root location of your webpage.
example:
webpage location: c:\MyWebPage\mywebpage.htm
css location: c:\MyWebPage\Desktop\task\style.css